# Привітання для електронного спілкування

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова, стилістика, етикет

Як краще вітатися в електронному вигляді? Себто електронною поштою, в месенджерах, і т. ін.

- *Добрий день/ранок/вечір* - не підходять, бо співрозмовник не факт що прям зараз прочитає.
- *Вітаю* - занадто урочисте, ближче до *поздоровляю*
- *Здрастуйте*, *привіт*, *здоровенькі були*, *салют* - фамільярні. Незнайомцю такого не скажеш

Єдиний більш-менш прийнятний варіант знайшов на [форумі r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=814) - *Доброго здоров'я*. Але й він, здається, рідко вживаний.

Comment: Не знаю, чомусь _вітаю_ не здає сї урочистим, часто особисто так пишу мережею.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Відповідно до **[Етикету ділового листування](http://pidruchniki.com/1031020840649/dokumentoznavstvo/etiket_dilovogo_listuvannya)**

> Починати листа необхідно із звертання, яке є загальноприйнятою формою
>   ввічливості. Проблема вибору звертання є доволі делікатною.
>   Найпоширенішими є такі звертання:
>
> Шановний (ім 'я та по батькові)!
>
> Шановний пане/пані... (ім 'я, ім'я й прізвище)!
>
> Шановні панове!
>
> Шановні колеги!
>
> Вельмишановний добродію!
>
> Глибокошановний (ім 'я та по батькові)!
>
> Високошановний пане...!

Із сайту HI-NEWS (не надійне та неофіційне джерело) **[Правила ділової переписки по електронній пошті.](http://hi-news.pp.ua/internet/6582-pravila-dlovoyi-perepiski-po-elektronny-posht-dloviy-list-zrazok-yak-vdpraviti-list-po-elektronny-posht.html)**

> Оптимальним вітальним словосполученням є ***«Добрий день»*** або ж
>   ***«Добридень»***. Ведення ділового листування по електронній пошті обмежує
>   відправника у використанні словосполучень «Добрий вечір» або «Доброго
>   ранку», так як одержувач може прочитати лист набагато пізніше його
>   отримання. Також не коректно використовувати у вітанні просторічні
>   вирази, що вживаються в неформальному спілкуванні. Після слова або
>   словосполучення вітання слід звернутися до одержувача по імені і по
>   батькові, а у випадку, якщо ім'я невідомо відправнику, цей момент
>   можна пропустити.

[Усне ділове мовлення](http://pidruchniki.com/1594040138386/dokumentoznavstvo/usne_dilove_movlennya#67)

> Вітання, Здавна в Україні живе добра традиція: вітатися з людьми
>   незалежно від близькості знайомства...
>
> Сьогодні набули певного поширення такі форми вітання: Доброго дня
>   (ранку, вечора), Вітаю Вас, Олександре Степановичу, або ***Доброго
>   здоров'я***, пані Галино. За сучасним діловим етикетом першим
>   вітається молодший із старшим, підлеглий з керівником, студент з
>   викладачем.

Хоч і рідко вживаний, але прийнятний варіант ***Доброго здоров'я***.

Особисто, я використовую ***"Добрий день"***  не залежно від того, коли буде прочитаний лист або ***"Шановна/Шановний"***, якщо знаю ім'я.

Comment: А як Ви дивитеся на мій варіант, **_Доброго здоров'я_**?

Comment: Щодо _**Шановний**_ - для пошти норм, а от для месенджерів якось наче вже й занадто офіційно

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk ***Доброго здоров'я***, на мою думку, також прийнятний варіант.

Comment: Маріє, щоб прийняти Вашу відповідь, можна Вас попросити додати _**Доброго здоров'я**_ у неї?

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk Ваше прохання виконано